# Make junit4 a synonym of junit

Tags: support, stack-overflow, synonym-request

**Update**
Since this is now a year old and I thought about this often, I propose the following:

- Make junit4 a synonym of junit
- keep the junit3 Tag

The benefit would be a clearer tag-structure for junit and we will be rid of double tags [junit](/questions/tagged/junit)[junit4](/questions/tagged/junit4)

Sadly, I can't propose a synonym on SO myself, because thats not allows for version tags.

---

Hi,

I hope this is the right place to adress this ;). I saw that this kind of issue was adressed with other tags here before.

I noticed that there are at 3 Junit-tags on stackoverflow, which are both used frequently but without distinction: [junit](/questions/tagged/junit) and [junit4](/questions/tagged/junit4) / [junit3](/questions/tagged/junit3).

Junit4 is the newer Framework for tests, that is based on annotations. But the same kind of questions are also tagged with junit.
I think there is no need to keep those tags separated, nowadays most tests are written with the junit 4 Framework (without knowing, that this is the new way).

Junit4-Question with Junit Tag: [Cannot capture exception details in @Override in JUnit4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571695/cannot-capture-exception-details-in-override-in-junit4), [JUnit @Test expected annotation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550175/junit-test-expected-annotation-not-working)

Comment: +1, Needless to say JUnit 4 is already 5 years old.

Comment: At least "junit3" should stay separate, as it can be used to indicate usage of that (rather old, but still used) version. I see no reason to remove that tag.

Comment: some people don't seem to know there is any difference. This question has all 3 Tags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845990/maven-3-and-junit-4-compilation-problem-package-org-junit-does-not-exist. I think it is utterly confusing, to have 3 junit Tags, when people seem to confuse what they stand for.

Answer (score 2):

And what when junit5 appears? [junit](/questions/tagged/junit) should be used for general *JUnit* questions, and [junit3](/questions/tagged/junit3) or [junit4](/questions/tagged/junit4) for questions specific only for given version of *JUnit*. In my opinion such synonimization would be misleading in many cases.

Comment: Sadly you can't tell people how a tag should be used. They just use it. And as is stated in my question they use it wrong.

Comment: You should retag such questions, if you met some.

Answer (score 1):

I propose to either:

A) do nothing as I can't decide JUnit should be better off as a synonym for JUnit3 or JUnit4 (newer isn't always right, otherwise Windows 8 would be a synonym for Windows)

B) block JUnit to force people to pick a version (probably the one they are actually using)

Comment: b) won't work. You'd have to retag every single junit question to junit3 or junit4 before that! And junit3 is so old, most people will only use junit4 now and maybe won't even know about version numbers. This tag should be transparent for users and not more complicated :D